# Limit generic type in subinterface in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

Say I have this interface structure:

```
public interface ItemRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest> {
    Target convert(IR request);
}

public interface CreateItemRequestConverter<CIR extends CreateItemRequest>
    extends ItemRequestConverter<ItemRequest> {
}

public class CreatePartRequestConverter implements CreateItemRequestConverter<CreatePartRequest> {
    @Override
    public Target convert(CreatePartRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I wondering whether this is possible at all. I doubt that.
When I create `CreatePartRequestConverter` the signature of the overridden method is the super type `ItemRequest`. This is not desired.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? I don't quite understand.

Comment: Why not extend `ItemRequestConverter<CIR>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your CreateItemRequestConverter class signature should be like this :

```
interface CreateItemRequestConverter<CIR extends CreateItemRequest>
        extends ItemRequestConverter<CIR> {

}
```

Test :

```
interface ItemRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest> {
    Target convert(IR request);
}

interface CreateItemRequestConverter<CIR extends CreateItemRequest>
        extends ItemRequestConverter<CIR> {

}

class CreatePartRequestConverter implements CreateItemRequestConverter<CreatePartRequest> {
    @Override
    public Target convert(CreatePartRequest request) {
        return null;
    }
}

class ItemRequest {
}

class CreateItemRequest extends ItemRequest {
}

class CreatePartRequest extends CreateItemRequest {
}

class Target {
}
```

Comment: Stupid me, that is perfect! Merci Olivier!

Answer (score 0):

So you want to make the overridden method accept a generic type that extends ItemRequest? You'll want to use a generic method, e.g:

```
<T extends ItemRequest> Target convert(T request);
```