# Create generic factory with generic subtype object in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, factory

I have written a [converter structure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21457226/696632) in Java for which I'd like to create a factory.

My basic idea is that I pass in a class of a valid type and receive a valid subtype converter but fail with the generics and inheritance part.

This is my interface:

```
interface ItemRequestConverterFactory {

  public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> newInstance(Class<IR> clazz);

}
```

and the implementation:

```
public class DefaultItemRequestConverterFactory implements ItemRequestConverterFactory {

  @Override
  public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> newInstance(Class<IR> clazz) {
    if (clazz.equals(CreatePartRequestConverter.class))
    return new CreatePartRequestConverter();

    return null;
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, Eclipse says: "Type mismatch: cannot convert from CreatePartRequestConverter to ItemRequestConverter".

Where is the problem in my generic signature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have a mismatch between the type parameters and the types that they should actually represent: You are passing a `Class<IR>` to the `newInstance` method. This is a class that represents an `ItemRequest`. However, you are comparing this class instance to a class that is probably an implementation of the `ItemRequestConverter` interface.

Although this compiles when you add an appropriate type parameter to the `CreatePartRequestConverter` class, it's probably not what you want to achieve:

```
interface ItemRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest>{}
interface ItemRequest{}
interface ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{
    public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> newInstance(Class<IR> itemRequestClass);
}
class CreatePartRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest> implements ItemRequestConverter<IR>
{
}

class DefaultItemRequestConverterFactory implements ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{

    @Override
    public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> newInstance(Class<IR> itemRequestClass) 
    {
        // Does not make sense: Comparing ItemRequest class with something
        // that is probably an implementation of ItemRequestConverter
        if (itemRequestClass.equals(CreatePartRequestConverter.class))
        {
            return new CreatePartRequestConverter<IR>();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you could pass the `ItemRequestConverter` class to the factory method (and parameterize the method accordingly) :

```
interface ItemRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest>{}
interface ItemRequest{}
interface ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{
    public <IRC extends ItemRequestConverter<?>> ItemRequestConverter<?> newInstance(Class<IRC> itemRequestConverterClass);
}
class CreatePartRequestConverter implements ItemRequestConverter<ItemRequest>
{
}

class DefaultItemRequestConverterFactory implements ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{
    @Override
    public <IRC extends ItemRequestConverter<?>> ItemRequestConverter<?> newInstance(
        Class<IRC> itemRequestConverterClass)
    {
        if (itemRequestConverterClass.equals(CreatePartRequestConverter.class))
        {
            return new CreatePartRequestConverter();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you also need the information about the `ItemRequest` class, the method signatures may start to become a little bit nasty, and one would have to analyze in more detail *where* and *how* this type information should be provided or used.

---

**EDIT** for the comment:

I think that this is not possible in a (compile-time) type-checked way. The problem here is that at the point where you create and return the new `ItemRequestConverter`, you can not say for sure that it is an `ItemRequestConverter` whose type parameter is `IR`. Or the other way around: You can't detect at compile-time that the type parameter of `CreatePartRequestConverter` (namely, `CreatePartRequest`) is the same as `IR`.

Based on the code snippets discussed so far, I *think* that it *should* be possible to simply cast in this case. The responsibility of making sure that the cast is valid is then left to the one who implements the "runtime-type-check":

```
if (itemRequestClass.equals(CreatePartRequest.class))
{
    CreatePartRequestConverter result = new CreatePartRequestConverter();
    return (ItemRequestConverter<IR>) result;
}
```

because nothing prevents you from writing

```
//                          !!!
if (itemRequestClass.equals(SomeCompletelyDifferentRequest.class))
{
    CreatePartRequestConverter result = new CreatePartRequestConverter();
    return (ItemRequestConverter<IR>) result;
}
```

So it *should* be valid to do this:

```
interface ItemRequestConverter<IR extends ItemRequest>{}
interface ItemRequest{}
interface ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{
    public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> 
        newInstance(Class<IR> itemRequestClass);
}

class CreatePartRequest implements ItemRequest {}
class CreatePartRequestConverter 
    implements ItemRequestConverter<CreatePartRequest> {}

class DefaultItemRequestConverterFactory implements ItemRequestConverterFactory 
{
    @Override
    public <IR extends ItemRequest> ItemRequestConverter<IR> newInstance(
            Class<IR> itemRequestClass)
    {
        if (itemRequestClass.equals(CreatePartRequest.class))
        {
            CreatePartRequestConverter result = new CreatePartRequestConverter();
            return (ItemRequestConverter<IR>) result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public class GenericFactoryTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ItemRequestConverterFactory factory = null;
        ItemRequestConverter<CreatePartRequest> converter = 
            factory.newInstance(CreatePartRequest.class);        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I want to achieve. My goal is: `ItemRequestConverter<CreatePartRequest> converter = factory.newInstance(CreatePartRequest.class)`.

Comment: I have already assued something like this. A cast is necessary. The main cause is probably type erasure.